# Why doesn't this code compile?

Tags: errors, graphs

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetGraphUnit{2}
\Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D}
\Edges(A,B,C,D,A,C)
\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{red}{B,D}
\AddVertexColor{green}{A}
\AddVertexColor{blue}{C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to load the correct package from tkz-collection.

Comment: I have package tikz

Comment: `tikz` is not enough. You need some of the `tkz` packages that build upon `tikz`

Comment: The commands `\GraphInit`, `\SetGraphUnit`, `\Vertices` and so on are not provided by `\usepackage{tikz}`, but by another package based on TikZ. Possibly `\usepackage{tkz-graph}`.

Comment: Daleif, now, with your suggestion, I solved the problem

Comment: In the future try to include the error message you received at the point the compilation halted.  That is useful information that can help others (or maybe even yourself) solve the problem.

Comment: Please consider working out more descriptive titles for your questions: you've asked a number that are rather vague or of the form 'Why doesn't X work?'. We are all happy to try to help with answers, but good questions should be accessible to others, and that does mean some effort in asking them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands you use are not standard TikZ commands, but rely on an extension of it called `tkz-graph`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-graph} % <---- HERE!

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetGraphUnit{2}
\Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D}
\Edges(A,B,C,D,A,C)
\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{red}{B,D}
\AddVertexColor{green}{A}
\AddVertexColor{blue}{C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using an additional package works. See your code with this package below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph} % needed package
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetGraphUnit{2}
\Vertices{circle}{A,B,C,D}
\Edges(A,B,C,D,A,C)
\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{red}{B,D}
\AddVertexColor{green}{A}
\AddVertexColor{blue}{C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This compiles to the following

[image: Example]

A more in depth question using the same package can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118044/alignement-of-tikz-pictures-and-tables-in-subfigures) (also on stackexchange).